# Sum multiple columns using vlookup in vba

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to sum multiple columns using vlookup within vba. I can do it as an Excel formula in this manner

```
{=SUM(VLOOKUP(LookupValue,LookupRange,{FirstColumnNo,2ndColumnNo,...,LastColumnNo},0))}
```

Within VBA, I don't seem to have any luck using that as I am also using a For loop with this formula. You can sum a lot of these lookups but I'm looking for something shorter and elegant

My current code

```
For i = 1 To ProdCurrentQtr
''''''''Gross Values
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 2) & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 3)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 5) = Application.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 1), LookupRangeCentral, 6, 0) _
+ Application.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 1), LookupRangeCentral, 7, 0) _
+ Application.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 1), LookupRangeCentral, 8, 0) _
+ Application.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 1), LookupRangeCentral, 9, 0) _
+ Application.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 1), LookupRangeCentral, 10, 0) _
+ Application.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 1), LookupRangeCentral, 12, 0)
Next i
```

But what I'm looking for is something along the lines of

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 5).FormulaArray = Application.Sum(Application.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 1), LookupRangeCentral, [6,7,8,9,10,12], 0))
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(8,1)
       For i = 1 To ProdCurrentQtr
         .Offset(i) = .Offset(i, 1) & "_" & .Offset(i, 2)
          Set found = LookupRangeCentral.Find(What:=.Offset(i), LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
          If Not found Is Nothing Then .Offset(I, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(found.Offset(,5).Resize(,7)) - found.Offset(,10)
       Next i
    End With
```

The array formula approach would be the following

```
   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(9,1)
       .Resize(ProdCurrentQtr).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1] & "" _ "" & RC[2]"
       .Offset(,4).FormulaArray = "=SUM(VLOOKUP(" & .Address(False, False) & "," & LookupRangeCentral.Address(,,,True) & ",{6,7,8,9,10,12},0))"
       .Offset(,4).AutoFill Destination:=.Offset(,4).Resize(ProdCurrentQtr)
   End With
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But can I ask what the third line of your code does? Because that's where the code doesn't run. In my code, the i is the number of rows that the code goes through from the starting of the table to the end. But I don't understand what .Offset(i) = .Offset(i, 1) & "_" & .Offset(i, 2) does? Isn't offset just offset (rows, columns)? And there is no underscore to concatenate them

Comment: The third line, in that it follows the 1st, does exactly what did you line: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 2) & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(i + 8, 3).  What's the error throw by this line?

Comment: (Continue) "Offset()" method actually offsets from the Range it is called upon. Since this latter is "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(8,1)" then ".Offset(i)" references "...Cells(8+ i, 1+0)" and ".Offset(i,2)" references "...Cells(8+ i, 1+2)" and so on...

Comment: It comes up with an error - Runtime error 424 - object required

Comment: Also if this helps - LookupRangeCentral is a different workbook in case. It is opened using a FileName and a LocationName both of which were declared as strings

Comment: Which line is highlighted when the code stops throwing error 424?

Comment: The missing underscore was in a previous "edition" I had already corrected. The "object required" error, if thrown by 3rd line, could only mean that "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Central").Cells(8,1)" is "Nothing" so you should only check for sheet "Central" to be actually present in the workbook where the macro resides in. Finally I edited my answer addeing an "array formula" approach

Comment: @AbeyGeorge did you get through it?

Comment: @AbeyGeorge: it'd be nice from you to give feedback on attempts at helping you

Comment: Yeah. Thanks guys. It didn't work. Unfortunately - had a deadline and did a simple sum of the vlookups instead. I'll post next week on the exact error

Answer (score 0):

The following formula does what you want.  Just an option:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX((ISNUMBER(MATCH(A11:A16,A2:A6&"_"&B2:B6,0)))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("," & COLUMN(B11:G16)& ",",",2,4,6,7,")))*B11:G16,))
```

The `",2,4,6,7,"` are the actual column numbers, not the relative.

This is summing the values in the above columns where the names are found in A2:A6&"_"&B2:B6.

[image]